# the output of this simple c program is hard to understand

Tags: c

I have written the bellow code in C.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   char c;
   c=400;
   printf("%d",c);
}
```

the output is -112. why?
if I have used unsigned char the output will be 144. why?

Comment: First tell, what did your C book told you about the range of a `char` type?

Comment: it says that it is 8 bits.

Comment: @delsa range is one thing and size is another thing.

Comment: it is c, and I can't understand what do you mean by range. the book doesn't have detailed explanations about range.

Comment: @delsa Hint: what is the maximum value you can write using 8 bits?

Comment: the maximum is 2^8-1

Comment: @delsa decimal value, and try to understand how 400 can fit in there... Hope you got the pointer

Comment: Hint: `-128+16`....`400-256=144`--->binary `(1)0010000`

Comment: I really don't understand downvotes at this question.... It is a good question for beginners.

Comment: its binary is 0000 0001 1001 0000 and only the left part can be fitted. so the result is 144 in decimal. but how the result is -112?

Comment: So you take left 8 bits: `1001 0000`. How negative numbers are represented? Try to think about it.

Comment: @LPs Because the answer can be found with minimum effort, by reading the first chapter of a beginner-level C programming book? SO is not an interactive beginner tutorial, contrary to what many seem to think.

Comment: why do you want to change that to negative. there is no evidence in code to indicate that? see the code. in the unsigned situation, the answer is obvious, but when deceleration is char ch, the output is odd.

Comment: Because `char` is signed rather than ( as you said), `unsigned char` are unsigned...

Comment: ok, suppose you are right and it is signed char, so what? can you tell me the reason?

Comment: @Lundin For beginners, sometimes, it is hard to understand what to search... BTW ok I can agree with you.

Comment: @delsa Take a look ( and study ) [Two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)

Comment: you mean that the 1001 0000 is a representation in 2's complement?

Comment: @LPs That's why they should read a good book instead of aimlessly searching through various shitty, incorrect tutorials on the internet.

Comment: It is how numbers are represented on your platform..

Comment: OT. @delsa to directly answer to a user use @(nickname) in the comment body.

Comment: @LPs: The C Standard doesn't specify if plain `char` is signed or unsigned.

Comment: @KeineLust I forgot to write **_on your platform_** ;)

Answer (score 2):

thank to all users.

from what that I saw in comments, I reached to this conclusion that will end all discussions.
there are 3 different way for representing signed types.

1. signed magnitude
2. 1's complement
3. 2's complement

and in all of these representations, if the most significant bit is 1 then the number is negative and if it is 0 then the number is positive.
therefore, in this question, my computer uses 2's complement. As a result, 10010000 is a representation in 2's complement. its value is equal to the negative of 01110000=112, so the real result is -112.

however, when the type is unsigned, then the value of 400 must transfer to representation in binary but only there is enough space for 8 digits. Therefore, the representation will be 1001 0000 and since this is unsigned it is equal to 2^7+2^4=144.

Comment: Please note that in the real world outside the C standard, sign & magnitude and 1's complement is nonsense. Every single CPU that is produced in volumes uses 2's complement. Therefore you don't need to worry about the other two, they are an artificial concern that barely exist outside nerdy C standard debates. Focus on learning and understanding 2's complement.

Answer (score 0):

The type of the integer constant is int and when it is assigned to the type char, it is converted in an implementation-defined manner.

An implementation that satisfies your result works conceptually like this: add or subtract the range of the type (which is 256 in this case) from the value, until the value can be represented by the type.

Range of char in this case is: [-128,127] and 400 is not representable by type char.

Subtract 256, and the result 144 is still not representable.

Subtract again, and the result -112 is representable.

Comment: I would love to read constructive comments along with downvotes on a correct answer.

Comment: Also don't abuse the system and downvote if you don't like the answer or if you think the question should be closed. For the former you can vote on the question itself, for the latter you can vote or flag to close.